# Eliminating the variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

can you help me solve this exercise? Thanks.

Eliminate $x, y, z$ from the given equations
$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
bx^2 +lx + c &= 0\\
cy^2 + my + a &= 0\\
az^2 + nz + b &= 0\\
xyz &= 1
\end{array}\right.$$

I tried to multiply first three equations hoping to that there’s some factoring trick I could use. Besides that I don’t know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Use the quadratic formula.

Comment: Can’t believe forgot about that. Thanks.

Comment: @user642106 No problem!